# How to add custom options or fields to an Order Adjuster?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

How do you add options or custom fields to an OrderAdjuster in Commerce 2?

I'm migrating a website from Craft2 to Craft3 and need this, this is how I do it in Commerce 2:

```
$promotionsAdjuster->optionsJson = [
    'lineItemsAffected' => [$lineItem->id],
    'affectedDiscountId' => $adjustment->id,
    'removeAffectedDiscountAmount' => $adjustment->amount - ($lineItem->total*$adjustment->optionsJson['percentDiscount']),
    'percentageDiscount' => true
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it, you just need to use:

```
// `sourceSnapshot` can contain information to explain the adjustment
$adjustment->sourceSnapshot = [ 'data' => 'value' ];
```